# Best way to terminate fine gauge polyurethane magnet wire

Tags: soldering

I am winding custom coils with AWG 32 polyurethane coated magnet wire and need to solder the coil leads to ~AWG 24 standard insulated wire so that they can be connected to a terminal block.

What are the best practices to solder the wires and also provide some strain relief?

Comment: The actual soldering should be quite easy.  Some magnet wire is quite tricky to get the coating off without damaging the rest of the wire.  Torch and sandpaper works for me but for really fine wire or tricky stuff you might want an acid bath.  Strain relief can obviously be provided in a number of ways but if there is a bit of PCB nearby, solder pads are easy to work with.  Think about forces due to acceleration/vibration that will be on any unsecured bit of 32 guage if it loops through the air at all, not just the forces that can be transferred from the larger wire.

Comment: When you bare the insulation, if you use torch and sandpaper, use a heatsink (pliers, a bit of foil, whatever, to protect the insulation/varnish right up to the edge of where you are baring to when you torch.  If you're using an outer layer of insulation/epoxy/adhesive you may want to connect the wires, heat shrink the connection, varnish/glue it and then let the connection be securely bound up under the final layer of fibreglass tape/varnish.  If you do this right you may be able to avoid having to use a frame or peg for mechanical strain relief.

Comment: Just brainstorming, I won't put that as an answer because someone around here probably has a really good best practice for this.

Answer (score 2):

To strip the fine wires (AWG32 is not all that fine) with polyurethane insulation you can usually use a small solder pot. Set it a bit hotter than you would a bench soldering iron. If you use one of the very inexpensive ones, it helps to put a small thermocouple into the pot to monitor the temperature. A bit of peanut oil on the top will  prevent too much oxidation from occurring. Something with a 1-2" (25-50mm) inside diameter is adequate.

If the insulation won't burn away, you can use mechanical or chemical stripping.

Typically you'd tape some sturdy insulation material to the outside of the finished coil, splice the wires, insulate the joint if necessary, and then wrap more tape around the outside to secure the joint. Leave adequate slack on the fine wire so that it won't be drawn taut by thermal expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out if you can solder through the magnet wire coating.  Simply hold the wire in a blob of solder hanging off of your soldering iron.  If the insulation bubbles off after several seconds, add a touch of flux and see of the wire accepts the solder.

I have had to do in the past what you are trying to do.  I made sure that the magnet wire we used was solderable.  Wrap several turns of the thinner magnet wire around the thicker wire.  Apply active flux (Rosin or Rosin Mildly Activated (RMA)) to the connection and hold your soldering iron on the connection until the magnet wire insulation bubbles off.

You should wind up with a visibly good solder joint.